# Simple solution remove duplicates in JS array. Must use push or pop and forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, include

So, I'm still learning, so forgive the simple nature. But I'm trying to write a function called uniq(arr). If it worked it would return a new array without any duplicate values. It should not change the original array.

Here are two test calls which are currently not working. I'm not sure what the error implies
>
uniq([1, 2, 3])
Expected: [1, 2, 3] but got:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'copy.includes')

>
uniq(['a', 'a', 'b'])
Expected: ['a', 'b'] but got: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'copy.includes')

```
function uniq(arr) {
  var copy;
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!copy.includes(item)) {
      push.copy(item);}})
  return copy
}
```

Comment: `copy = []` and `push.copy(item)` -> `copy.push(item)`? Also, `uniq = a => [...new Set(a)];` is simpler, has better time complexity and should preserve order. The only advantage of `includes` here is that it doesn't allocate an object, which has one-time overhead.

Comment: `push.copy` => `copy.push` it's `object.method`, not `method.object`. (Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.)

Comment: Please ignore whoever taught you to put closing `}` on the same line as the last line of the block. It's an extraordinarily difficult style to read, understand, write, and modify. Put the `}` on their own line, aligned with the structure that started them. :-)

Comment: To make the comments above work you first have to store an array in `copy`. Right now it's just `undefined` -> `var copy = [];`

Comment: Wonderful @T.J.Crowder. The closing curly bracket is my user error. For reasons that may track back to my writing days, I hate singleton lines. Will try to use them going forward.

Comment: @EzraGreene - Ah, sorry, I assumed someone had taught you to do it like that, because I've seen several newer coders doing it... I'd've phrased things differently if I'd thought you'd done it on your own. :-D *(Never assume, Teej!)*

Comment: @EzraGreene - Note that you don't have to accept an answer. It seems like the one you've accepted doesn't do what you said you needed (*"Must use push or pop and forEach"*). You can unaccept that and either delete the question if you like, or post your own answer, or just leave the question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` makes an array unique.

```js
const unique = (arr) => {
  return [... new Set(arr)];
}

console.log(unique([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5]))
// Output: [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: And yet, doesn't use `push` or `pop` as the question says it must. If this were the answer, there'd be a dupetarget to select, rather than posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 issues with your code. 
The initial error comes from copy not having a value. You need to give it a value of an empty array to be able to call array methods on it e.g.

```
 var copy = [];
```

The second error is how you are using the `push` method. You need to call push on array not the other way around(see below)

```
copy.push(item);
```

Fixing these leaves us with this working example

```js
function uniq(arr) {
  var copy = [];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!copy.includes(item)) {
      copy.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  return copy;
}

console.log(uniq(['a', 'a', 'b']));
```